# cannot import name 'PlotLossesTensorFlowKeras' in jupyter notebook even though I have installed all dependencies

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

This problem appears on  my jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import utils
import os
%matplotlib inline

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D

#from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

from IPython.display import SVG, Image
from livelossplot import PlotLossesTensorFlowKeras
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version:", tf.__version__)
```

I have tried pip install livelossplot but no use.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue then what I did which worked for me is, replace that with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import utils
import os
%matplotlib inline

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout,Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

from IPython.display import SVG, Image
#from livelossplot import PlotLossesTensorFlowKeras
from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras
from livelossplot.keras import PlotLossesCallback
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version:", tf.__version__)
```

You may now proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

I think we followed the same tutorial in coursera.

The problem is a version mismatch

```
pip uninstall livelossplot

pip install livelossplot==0.5.2
```

Then use this

```
from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras
```

instead of the old one.